# Concise HTTP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

Here's my code for a consise node.js HTTP server.
It does work as intended, but I'd like to ask if there's any glitch or to be improved.

```
   var httpServer = function(dir)
    {
      var component = require('http')
        .createServer(function(req, res)
        {
          var fs = require('fs');
          var path = require("path");
          var url = require('url');

          var mimeTypes = {
            "html": "text/html",
            "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
            "jpg": "image/jpeg",
            "png": "image/png",
            "js": "text/javascript",
            "css": "text/css"
          };

          var uri = url.parse(req.url)
            .pathname;
          var filename = path.join(dir, unescape(uri));
          var indexFilename = path.join(dir, unescape('index.html'));
          var stats;

          console.log(filename);

          try
          {
            stats = fs.lstatSync(filename); // throws if path doesn't exist
          }
          catch (e)
          {
            res.writeHead(404,
            {
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.write('404 Not Found\n');
            res.end();
            return;
          }


          if (stats.isFile())
          {
            // path exists, is a file
            var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filename)
              .split(".")[1]];
            res.writeHead(200,
            {
              'Content-Type': mimeType
            });

            var fileStream =
              fs.createReadStream(filename)
              .pipe(res);
          }
          else if (stats.isDirectory())
          {
            // path exists, is a directory
            res.writeHead(200,
            {
              'Content-Type': "text/html"
            });
            var fileStream =
              fs.createReadStream(indexFilename)
              .pipe(res);
          }
          else
          {
            // Symbolic link, other?
            // TODO: follow symlinks?  security?
            res.writeHead(500,
            {
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.write('500 Internal server error\n');
            res.end();
          }

        });

      return component;
    };


    var port = 9999;
    var dir = 'www';
    var HTTPserver =
      httpServer(require('path')
        .join(__dirname, dir))
      .listen(port, function()
      {
        console.log('HTTP listening ' + port);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simpler

```
var port = 9999;
var directory = 'www';

var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var path = require("path");
var fs = require('fs');

var mimeTypes = {
  "html": "text/html",
  "js": "text/javascript",
  "css": "text/css",
  "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
  "jpg": "image/jpeg",
  "png": "image/png",
  "gif": "image/gif",
  "svg": "image/svg"
    // more
};

var request = function(req, res)
{
  var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  var dir = path.join(__dirname, directory);
  var filepath = path.join(dir, unescape(uri));
  var indexfilepath = path.join(dir, unescape('index.html'));

  console.info('filepath', filepath);

  var f = function(err, stats)
  {
    if (stats === undefined) // path does not exit 404
    {
      res.writeHead(404,
      {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      res.write('404 Not Found\n');
      res.end();

      return;
    }
    else if (stats.isFile()) // path exists, is a file
    {
      var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filepath).split(".")[1]];
      res
        .writeHead(200,
        {
          'Content-Type': mimeType
        });

      var fileStream =
        fs
        .createReadStream(filepath)
        .pipe(res);

      return;
    }
    else if (stats.isDirectory()) // path exists, is a directory
    {
      res
        .writeHead(200,
        {
          'Content-Type': "text/html"
        });

      var fileStream =
        fs
        .createReadStream(indexfilepath)
        .pipe(res);

      return;
    }
    else
    {
      // Symbolic link, other?
      // TODO: follow symlinks?  security?
      res
        .writeHead(500,
        {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        })
        .write('500 Internal server error\n')
        .end();

      return;
    }
  };

  fs.stat(filepath, f);
  return;
};

var serverUp = function()
{
  console.info('HTTP server listening', port);
  return;
};

var component = http
  .createServer(request)
  .listen(port, serverUp);
```

Comment: I propose to edit your other anser, instead of creating a new answer for each code improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You should move all `require(...)` calls to the very beginning of your code, instead of running `require` on each place locally.

In its current form, you won't see `require` errors until your server runs and receives its first requests. This is unfortunate. You usually want a program to fail as early as possible if it clearly won't work.

> [Rule of Repair (TAOUP)](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html#id2878538): Repair what you can — but when you must fail, fail noisily and as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I modified as follows, in addition to ensure require error possibility checking, structurally better I guess.
Plus, I modified to full async where it should be.

```
var httpServer = function(dir)
{
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require("path");
  var url = require('url');

  var mimeTypes = {
    "html": "text/html",
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css",
    "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    "jpg": "image/jpeg",
    "png": "image/png",
    "gif": "image/gif",
    "svg": "image/svg"
    // more
  };

  var component = require('http')
    .createServer(function(req, res)
    {
      var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
      var filepath = path.join(dir, unescape(uri));
      var indexfilepath = path.join(dir, unescape('index.html'));

      console.info('filepath', filepath);

      var f = function(err, stats)
      {
        if (stats === undefined) // path does not exit 404
        {
          res.writeHead(404,
          {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
          });
          res.write('404 Not Found\n');
          res.end();

          return;
        }
        else if (stats.isFile()) // path exists, is a file
        {
          var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filepath).split(".")[1]];
          res
            .writeHead(200,
            {
              'Content-Type': mimeType
            });

          var fileStream =
            fs
            .createReadStream(filepath)
            .pipe(res);

          return;
        }
        else if (stats.isDirectory()) // path exists, is a directory
        {
          res
            .writeHead(200,
            {
              'Content-Type': "text/html"
            });
          var fileStream =
            fs
            .createReadStream(indexfilepath)
            .pipe(res);

          return;
        }
        else
        {
          // Symbolic link, other?
          // TODO: follow symlinks?  security?
          res
            .writeHead(500,
            {
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            })
            .write('500 Internal server error\n')
            .end();

          return;
        }
      };

      fs.stat(filepath, f);

    });

  return component;
};


var port = 9999;
var dir = 'www';
var HTTPserver =
  httpServer(require('path')
    .join(__dirname, dir))
  .listen(port, function()
  {
    console.info('HTTP listening', port);
  });
```

Comment: What exactly were you simplifying? Could you explain rather than just showing? A whole new version of the code won't create much learning effect, especially since there is no easy diff mechanism here.